# How to format data in datagridview after retrieval

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a databound datagridview. I need to format the amount column to have commas for thousands after the data is retrieved. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in **Datagridview CellFormatting event** ..

Reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

And you can do format for the cell --> `Format(e.Value, "###,###,###")` 
But it will display depend on your regional setting .. it could `.` or `,`

Answer (score 0):

Does the grid itself have a string format parameter, if so you should be able to just set the string format to "N" [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)